What declaration to explicitly ask for an application/octet-stream content carried by an array of bytes parameter (and not a file or an object)?
For a REST client or server, next OpenAPI declaration asks for some file handling (upload or download):
content:
   application/octet-stream:
      schema:
         type: string
         format: binary

It is well handled by OpenApi generators, that generate methods like: myParameter(File file).
But currently, we are willing to carry an array of bytes (a pure octet-stream like the content type says). We wrote this declaration:
content:
   application/octet-stream:
      schema:
         type: object

in order to carry some binary data, but not in a file.
Binary data, because the caller of our REST service doesn't have to (and maybe: can't) tell more about what he is sending.
The problem we are facing

Currently, one OpenAPI generator (for Go language) generates an unexpected (but not wrong) method for us.
It does what we are asking it to do, and this is different of what we are willing to have...

func (r ApiTest1PostRequest) 
   Body(body map[string]interface{}) ApiTest1PostRequest


I'm willing to clarify this. Because we need this REST method generated to have getter/setters receiving this parameter as an array of bytes.

Currently, you could reply to us: "Yes. But for instance, it's a type: object you asked for".


This is obvious if we use some others generators
They create the following prototypes, in front of our OpenAPI declaration:
Java:
public okhttp3.Call 
   test1PostAsync(Object body, final ApiCallback<Object> _callback) throws ApiException

Java (Spring):
default ResponseEntity<Object> 
   test1Post(@Parameter(name = "body", description = "", required = true) 
      @Valid @RequestBody Object body)

C++ Rest SDK:
//  cpp-restsdk
pplx::task<std::shared_ptr<Object>> 
    DefaultApi::test1Post(std::shared_ptr<Object> body) const

They understand application/octet-stream, type: object to the will of carrying an Object. I think they are right!
So, there's first a declaration problem to solve in our OpenAPI declaration
The requester should not ask for:
application/octet-stream:
   schema:
     type: object

that carries an object.
Nor:
application/octet-stream:
   schema:
     type: string
     format: binary

that carries a File.
What should he ask for, in its OpenAPI declaration?
application/octet-stream:
   schema:
     type: array    # ???
     format: binary # ???

(independently of "would the generator be able to generate that?" → this I will try to manage by intervene in the OpenApi generator, if needed)
as the wish of the caller is to manage a byte[] content.
My final target is to have the proper OpenAPI declaration from which the generation of the following methods would be expected
Go:
func (r ApiTest1PostRequest) 
   Body(body []byte) ApiTest1PostRequest

Java:
public okhttp3.Call 
   test1PostAsync(byte[] body, final ApiCallback<Object> _callback) throws ApiException

C++ Rest SDK:
pplx::task<unsigned char[]> 
   DefaultApi::test1Post(unsigned char[] body) const

or:
pplx::task<std::byte[]> 
   DefaultApi::test1Post(std::byte[] body) const


Note: My question is related to an issue I'm willing to solve on OpenApi generator.
But my first problem is: what should I do? What should I have seen generated instead of what I have?
The problem isn't specific to the Go language where I've found the trouble: it's a general one, as I guess that most generators (for other languages) will fall into the same pit.

are you referring to octet-stream, not object-stream?  this is kind of a catch all media type to accept any type of content, rather than strictly defining something like application/pdf or application/json

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2046#section-4.5.1

The recommended action for an implementation that receives an
"application/octet-stream" entity is to simply offer to put the data
in a file, with any Content-Transfer-Encoding undone, or perhaps to
use it as input to a user-specified process.

This question is similar to: In a json schema, what is the correct way to describe a default, example, or enum value for a binary schema?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JeremyFiel Sorry. It's an application/octet-stream going to an object. Edited.
